# Matplotlib Histogram error

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, list-comprehension

```
mu = a number
sigma = a number
x = [some ints]
num_bins = [int(mu + sigma*x) for x in range(-5,6)]

plt.hist(x, bins = num_bins)
```

returns TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `x` as the free variable in the list comprehension and it "stomped" the other `x` from the previous line.